# finding an elegant way to dynamically get config object

Tags: java, spring, properties, configuration

i want to manage the config of my app by using Spring Configuration Properties(i dont want my app becoming a spring application). I have lots of config classes, i cant make it to dynamically read config.

#### Here is my config class(more Account class may be added after):

```
package org.oval.ddi.ws.config;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "ws.remote", ignoreInvalidFields = true)
@PropertySource(encoding="UTF-8", value = "classpath:DDIConfig.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
public class Account {
    private String remoteServiceUrl;

    private String wsAction;
    private String logAction;
    private String apiId;
    private String type;
    private int outTime;
    private String wsSpaceNameRemote;
    private String query;

    private String log;

    public String getLogAction() {
        return logAction;
    }

    public void setLogAction(String logAction) {
        this.logAction = logAction;
    }

    public String getApiId() {
        return apiId;
    }

    public void setApiId(String apiId) {
        this.apiId = apiId;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public int getOutTime() {
        return outTime;
    }

    public void setOutTime(int outTime) {
        this.outTime = outTime;
    }

    public String getWsSpaceNameRemote() {
        return wsSpaceNameRemote;
    }

    public void setWsSpaceNameRemote(String wsSpaceNameRemote) {
        this.wsSpaceNameRemote = wsSpaceNameRemote;
    }

    public String getQuery() {
        return query;
    }

    public void setQuery(String query) {
        this.query = query;
    }

    public String getLog() {
        return log;
    }

    public void setLog(String log) {
        this.log = log;
    }

    public String getRemoteServiceUrl() {
        return remoteServiceUrl;
    }

    public void setRemoteServiceUrl(String remoteServiceUrl) {
        this.remoteServiceUrl = remoteServiceUrl;
    }

    public String getWsAction() {
        return wsAction;
    }

    public void setWsAction(String wsAction) {
        this.wsAction = wsAction;
    }

    @EnableConfigurationProperties(Account.class)
    static class DDIConfiguration {
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        context.register(DDIConfiguration.class);
        context.refresh();
        Account account = context.getBean(Account.class);
        context.close();
    }


}
```

#### Here is my properties file:

```
ws.remote.remoteServiceUrl=saasasasasas
ws.remote.wsAction=assasasasas
ws.remote.logAction=asasasasa
ws.remote.apiId=asasa
ws.remote.type=0
ws.remote.outTime=80000
ws.remote.wsSpaceNameRemote=assasasasas
ws.remote.query=asasasasasas
ws.remote.log=asasasasasasas
```

#### I create bean instance like this:

```
import org.oval.ddi.ws.config.Account;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class test{
    @EnableConfigurationProperties(Account.class)
    static class AccountConfiguration {

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        context.register(AccountConfiguration.class);
        context.refresh();
        Account account = context.getBean(Account.class);

        context.close();


    }
}
```

an elegant way to read different config class.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "Properties" class. Something similar to the following:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "ws.remote") //notice the prefix
public class Properties {

  private String remoteServiceUrl;
  private String wsAction;
  // ...
  // keep going, and keep the literal names of the properties file

  public void setRemoteServiceUrl(String remoteServiceUrl) {
    this.remoteServiceUrl = remoteServiceUrl;
  }

  public String getRemoteServiceUrl() {
    return this.remoteServiceUrl;
  }

  // write all setters and getters!! otherwise you won't be able to work with them
}
```

This way you can work dinamically with the parameters you'd like to use. Notice that you can have multiple classes such as WSProperties, MyProperties, NiceProperties... each of them with one specific prefix.

It is similar to what you already have, but this should be enough to work dinamically without problems.

Hope this helps.